# Disconnected winding phenomenon

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

ST AN1946 p.10 says: "The zero-crossing detection can also be done when PWM is in an "ON" state if the compare value is set to the half value of the DC bus."

It makes complete sense, if we're assuming that the other two windings are just a voltage divider. But we're observing the phenomenon that the voltage value during PWM is not half DC but higher. Somehow it depends on the duty cycle and who knows what else.

I measured and plotted ADC values on a disconnected winding; the green line represents the Vdc/2. On the scale, you can see the actual zero-crossing time, and at that time the offset is far from Vdc/2. What is causing this phenomenon? How to find the zero-crossing value when PWM is on? Thanks.

Measured and plotted ADC values on a disconnected winding:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're talking about windings in a (presumably running) motor there could be some magnetical field remaining giving EMF. When you disconnect a winding it's not actively pulled to a rail by the bridge leg so it has to dissipate somehow. A similar phenomenon (the rotor still turning) is actually used for sensorless switching, which it seems its the thing you want to do.

The thing I don't really get is the step at about t=780, which seems from another data line… what would be its meaning

Comment: It is. I also can see this when a motor is NOT running. As soon as I connect this disconnected winding to the ESC board. https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/b-g431b-esc1.html . At this time one winding is powered with 10% PWM DC, another is grounded.